Activate chrome browser in VBA and activate specific tab
I am trying to activate chrome browser and this is the code I have
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If

Const SW_RESTORE As Long = 9

Dim foundWindowHandle As LongPtr
Dim targetTabTitle As String

Sub Test()
    targetTabTitle = "Google Chrome"
    foundWindowHandle = 0
    EnumWindows AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, 0
    If foundWindowHandle <> 0 Then
        ShowWindow foundWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE
        SetForegroundWindow foundWindowHandle
    End If
End Sub

Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    Dim windowTitle As String
    Dim titleLength As Long
    titleLength = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
    If titleLength > 0 Then
        windowTitle = String$(titleLength + 1, vbNullChar)
        GetWindowText hWnd, windowTitle, titleLength + 1
        windowTitle = Left$(windowTitle, titleLength)
        If InStr(1, windowTitle, targetTabTitle, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            foundWindowHandle = hWnd
            EnumWindowsProc = 0
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    EnumWindowsProc = 1
End Function

This works and makes the chrome browser activated. How can I activate WhatsApp tab?
This works but when the tab of WhatsApp is already active
Sub ActivateWhatsAppTab()
    targetTabTitle = "WhatsApp"
    foundWindowHandle = 0
    EnumWindows AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, 0
    If foundWindowHandle <> 0 Then
        ShowWindow foundWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE
        SetForegroundWindow foundWindowHandle
    End If
End Sub

But if another tab is active the code doesn't activate the desired tab

I don't know the exact solution to your question but, do you mind using a more simple VBA code to open https://web.whatsapp.com/ in your default Browser (FireFox, Chrome, MS Edge....) and bring it in front of Excel?
Sub Test()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open CVar(URL)
End Sub

